# What do you search for in Open Source code to be sure there isn't malicious code?

Tags: virus, .net, bash, c++

I realize the answers will be language specific, but I am curious what terms you would look for when checking something out on Github? I was looking for a remote administration tool that I could use with clients, and found some awesome ones, that happen to be "viruses"

Take https://github.com/rsmudge/vncdll (associated with metasploit), or the QuasarRAT project for example: https://github.com/quasar/QuasarRAT

Now I have seen enterprise high priced tools like SolarWinds MSP Connect, Dameware, and so on that do most of those same things, but QuasarRAT is listed as a virus when I try compiling it.

I was playing with the idea of taking the QuasarRAT program apart, segmenting each feature into plugins, remove any that may be malicious only, but then I am not sure it still wouldn't be listed as a virus.

In PHP I would look for obfuscated code that was using base64_decode(), exec() and so on, but I am curious what terms I should be on the lookout for with C#, C++ C, Bash - specifically those that may involve keylogging, transmitting data to a remote host, or downloading additional things to the computer?

Things I can think of are TcpListener, AcceptTcpClient, stream, bind, sockets, http, wget, curl, ftp, ssh, rsync. Since I am not fluent in C++, C, and I know I have more to learn in Bash and C#, I would love suggestions for those fun Easter eggs that people have hidden that you have found.

While I realize that just because these terms are used, it doesn't mean it IS malicious, but at least I can focus some time on that function and decide what it is doing, what else is calling it, and if it is approved.

IF we can get a good list together, I will try to come up with a script that will automatically search and bring back the matches for review.

Comment: If you're doing this as a fun learning exercise, then carry on! But if you're planning on using the results for something serious, then know that you're fighting a serious uphill battle; especially in C, for any search list you come up with, I can write a malicious program that it doesn't catch. If you're willing to put in that much effort, why not pay for a tool that comes with some reputation?

Comment: Thanks Mike, I haven't found a tool yet that I can integrate with my own application. I have found tools that let me rebrand their application like RemoteUtilities.com, but I can't integrate that within my application like I wanted. Many of my customers already have a remote desktop tool, but it is managed by a 3rd party IT company that is generally reluctant to share login credentials. I plan on having an option during install to enable remote support and having it all be part of the main app.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be 100% sure that some git repo doesn't contain malicious code, write it yourself; anything else will be an uphill battle.

If someone's really truly trying to hide malicious code in plain sight, then you probably won't notice it. Take for example, the infamous [2003 nearly-a-backdoor in the Linux kernel](https://freedom-to-tinker.com/2013/10/09/the-linux-backdoor-attempt-of-2003/) where this harmless code:

```
if ((options == (__WCLONE|__WALL)) && (current->uid == 0))
    retval = -EINVAL;
```

was turned into a backdoor like so:

```
if ((options == (__WCLONE|__WALL)) && (current->uid = 0))
    retval = -EINVAL;
```

(hint: instead of checking if you're root `uid == 0`, it turns you into root `uid = 0`. So pass in the flags `_WCLONE|_WALL` to whatever system call this is and BAM! you're now root.)

This example isn't directly relevant, but shows that malicious code in C/C++ can be *really* subtle. So if you think there's a chance that someone is playing hide-and-seek games in the code, move on and find a different project.

---

I often deal with a softer version of your question, "Is this open source library / tool ok to use?". My approach is to see if it has a good reputation; is it actively maintained? Do their github tickets give the impression that they follow a proper dev process? Do they publish regular changelogs, including security fixes? Does it have unresolved CVEs against it? If there are binaries, are they properly code-signed?

It's not foolproof, but it weeds out seedier projects. *(if anyone has a better way of vetting open source projects, I'd love suggestions!)*

Comment: Wow Mike, that is super sneaky, I guess `uid` should be on the list for sure. I had to read that a couple times to find what was different.

Comment: That example is from code running inside the linux kernel itself, so setting `uid = 0` in an application won't do anything. Just an example to show that people can be more clever than what you can detect with ctrl+f pattern matching.